# PieCloudDB database's connection configuration

Tags: ssl, connection

Does PieCloudDB database support SSL/TLS transport encryption?

and how to configure it when connecting to PieCloudDB via SQL Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PieCloudDB database supports SSL/TLS transport encryption. Taking the dbeaver tool as an example. You can designate the host, port, database, and username information in the visual client tool. And configure the CA certificate, client certificate, and client key in the SSL interface. The relevant certificate and key need to be obtained from the PieCloudDB server. Remember to choose "verify-ca" for the SSL mode.

The specific configuration information is as follows:
[image]
[image]